# can i retrieve Asp.net Session From MySql Trigger

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to Log the User Activity From A trigger that Who and What the user has changed in the table for a particular column. I know i cant access the url but is there any way i can get the value of the User who was logged in and updated something.

My Trigger Code is :

```
CREATE Trigger `Drfafterupdate`
after update 
on `drftemplate` for each row
Begin 
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
SELECT USER() INTO vUser;

Insert into logdbchanges (Username,OldValue,NewValue,TableName,ColumnName,Url,DateTime) 
Values (vUser,(select Old.WaterSourceNotes from `drftemplate` where DRFTemplateId = OLD.DRFTemplateId),(select WaterSourceNotes from `drftemplate` where DRFTemplateId = New.DRFTemplateId),'drftemplate','','',Now());

END
```

Here I am Getting the value of **MySQL User** that i have written in Web.config but i want the Asp.net Session User in the column **Username**. Is it Possible and How..??

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `session data` from `controller` and `view` only, not in MySQL queries. So create a log function in some dbmanager class and pass the session username value to the function and then write that value to database from the dbmanager class.

Comment: Like Context_info in SQL Server, Isn't there anything in MySQL. I cant change the code everywhere in my project as i want this at many tables. @ViVi

Comment: it is something related to client side. How can it be accessible inside the database. The best thing to do is to create a function and then use this function to log the data. @Minksmnm

Comment: But what if session mode is changed to save in sql. can i retrieve it then.?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: if i use SQL session mode where session is stored in SQL, can i access it then.? @ViVi

Comment: Read [this article on MySql Session state for ASP.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/633199/using-mysql-session-state-provider-for-asp-net) or else why don't you store the current active user data in database and use some kind of stored procedure to automatically log the data? @Minksmnm